# Avoiding Duplicate Value Insert for a specific time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I do not want to allow duplicate records in my SQL Server Table for 5 minutes.
Means, duplicate value is ok but it should be at least 5 minutes apart.

I tried
If Not Exists,
but in high load conditions, sometimes even this fails.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Please note, Unique Key Constraint won't work. We want to stop a duplicate value insertion for 5 minutes only.

```
If Not Exists (Select 1 from TheTable 
Where DuplicateElement = @element and AddedOnTime >= DATEADD(minute, -5, GetDate()))
Begin
Insert into TheTable (DuplicateElement, AddedOnTime)
values (@element, GetDate())
Select 1
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES` like this:

```
insert into TheTable (DuplicateElement, AddedOnTime)
select @element, GetDate()
where not exists (
  select 1 from TheTable 
  where DuplicateElement = @element and AddedOnTime >= DATEADD(minute, -5, GetDate())
)
```

Comment: This could still insert dups if concurrent queries run at the same time. One way to avoid that is with `SELECT 1 FROM TheTable WITH(UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)`. I would also suggest a primary key, unique constraint, or unique index on DuplicateElement and AddedOnTime.